# How can I get a User object returned when authenticating with ASP.NET Identity 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

This authentication normally just involves calling the '/Token' endpoint, with **user credentials**, and receiving a ticket back containing an auth token for the **user**. I am calling this in my Web API from a WPF client application, and it would make life much easier for me, and the login process much quicker, if I could simple have one authentication request that returns the authenticated `IdentityUser`, or in a normal template based API project, an `AspNetUser` object.

I see the method `TokenEndPoint` in my API's `ApplicationOAuthProvider` does very little, so I don't think a change there could help much, but the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` seems to be the crux of that provider, yet its return is void.

The options for the provider include:

AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin")

but I can find no evidence of that action being executed. I trace all successful requests to a log, and my `Debug.WriteLine($"API TRACE: ExternalLogin called for {provider}.")` doesn't appear in the output window, so I don't think I can use that action to server redirect to one that returns a User.

Is there anything I can do, except call the `/Token` endpoint from a login action that allows anonymous, and then redirect?

**EDIT:** The method that grants the token is in the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class provided in my project template. It derives from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. It is:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<UserManager>();
    var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", $"The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }
    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you need windows authentication so not token is required? Then look at https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication. Otherwise, what do you want that makes it easier than requesting a token based on credentials and pass that token in every request in a header? What would you gain?

Comment: @PeterBons No, none of that. When the token is granted, see my edit above, the user requesting it is also signed in. I would like to get that user back in the same response I get the token back. I think the question subject hints at that, and the text makes an effort to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do a `Server.Transfer` within the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method of the `ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class. This is provided out-the-box in the either the project template or a Nuget package.

The transfer would be to an added `Login` method in the `AccountController`, with username, password, and an additional `ticket` parameter, which will return an `AspNetUser` user class, to which you can add an extra property for the authentication ticket obtained in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` and normally returned by the `/Token` resource.

But this is too much meddling in code not written by me, so for this urgent prototype of the project, I just call `/Token`, and when I have the username, I call `/User` to get the now signed in `AspNetUser`.